# Connecting TFS 2012 express to sql server express installed on another PC

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs, sql-server-express

I have installed Team foundation server 2012 **express**.But i  want TFS Express to use SQL Server Express installed on another PC. Is there any option so I can connect TFS Express 2012 to SQL Server Express installed on another PC?

Comment: What happens when you try it. _Have_ you tried it?

Comment: I didnt get any option in tfs express 2012 to try it

Comment: Does TFS Express come with the configuration console? Try it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use TFSConfig.exe command as the following:

- Open cmd as administrator
- Navigate to:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools
> directory (cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
> 11.0\Tools

- Run the following command:

> tfsconfig unattend /configure /type:basic
> /inputs:SqlInstance=PC2\TFSSQLExpress

**PC2**: is your second machine.

**TFSSQLExpress**: is the instance name.

**But there are a lot considerations you have to take:**

- If the TFS is already configured remove it's configuration first.

[image]

- be careful to to open the command line and running TFSConfig.exe with
  user account that has permission on the other machine so it can
  install DB there, it's better if you use Domain Controller account.
- Be careful that the SQL enabled for Remote Connection and the SQl
  Server Network Configuration.

[image]
[image]

- Make sure the configuration success.

  [image]